# Keras LSTM Autoencoder: Simple Sequential Input to a Sequential Output

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, autoencoder

I have a following sample 3d shape dataset

```
    X_train =  [[array([[0.32225183]]),
      array([[0.28631562]]),
      array([[0.30552849]]),
      array([[0.33142298]]),
      array([[0.28376102]])],
     [array([[0.28631562]]),
      array([[0.30552849]]),
      array([[0.33142298]]),
      array([[0.28376102]]),
      array([[0.20635083]])],
     [array([[0.30552849]]),
      array([[0.33142298]]),
      array([[0.28376102]]),
      array([[0.20635083]]),
      array([[0.26855856]])]]
```

Above data has a shape of 5 timestamps/sequence, 1 feature and 3 samples.

I am trying run a simple LSTM Autoencoder for the time series anomaly detection, so input is a sequence and output will be a sequence, the reconstruction error can tell me about anomaly at a particular time.

```
    import numpy as np 
    import pandas as pd 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    from numpy import array
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed
    from keras.utils import plot_model
    from keras import optimizers
    from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping


    lstm_autoencoder = Sequential()
##EncodingPart
    lstm_autoencoder.add(LSTM(units = 10, activation='relu', input_shape=(5, 1), return_sequences=True))

##DecodingPart

    lstm_autoencoder.add(LSTM(5, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    lstm_autoencoder.summary()

## Compile
    lstm_autoencoder.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=2, verbose=1) 
    lstm_autoencoder_history = lstm_autoencoder.fit(X_train, X_train, 
                                                epochs = 100, 
                                                batch_size = 10, 
                                                verbose=2, callbacks=[early_stop])
```

Usually, I flatten my output after the fitnpredict and compare the reconstruction error.

But it's giving me following error

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected lstm_8 to have shape (5, 5) but got array with shape (5, 1)
```

Please help me to get this simple sequential output

Comment: The expected output of the model is `(?,5,5)`, but the label you feed is `(?,5,1)`. You should change `lstm_autoencoder.add(LSTM(5, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))` to `lstm_autoencoder.add(LSTM(1, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))` when you confirm your output is `(?,5,1)`.

Comment: It is not giving sequence as output, instead everything is coming out as 0

Comment: The second `5` already represents the sequence output. The third `5` just represents the number of features, not the output of your sequence. The result of `0` may be that your activation function is not selected correctly.